# Is there a Blender equivalent to Maya's smooth target brush?

Tags: shape-keys, smooth

I'm trying to smooth out and deform a mesh for a shape key, where it will average out the geometry between the new shape and the original, like in Maya with a smooth target brush.

Answer (score 1):

> it will average out the geometry between the new shape and the original, like in Maya with a smooth target brush.

If you want to do this, you can use a "blend from shape" operation, setting the shape to Basis and disabling add.  The blend will determine how much you mix between the new shape and the original:

[image]

You can do this on only selected vertices if desired; you can do it on a copy of the shapekey.

Alternatively, you can use a vertex group, as smooth or sharp as you'd like, to modulate a shapekey:

[image]

If desired, this can be written into a new shapekey by pinning and using the "new shape from mix" operation, from the shapekey specials dropdown shown above.